# Как динамически вставить флеш-объект в html-страничку в IE11

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer

Я видел [рекомендации Адоба](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2015/10/flash-player-guidance-for-internet-explorer-11-and-microsoft-edge.html) по данному поводу, но у них дан пример по статическому добавлению флеш-контента. Когда я пытаюсь сделать это динамически, то ничего не выходит. Вернее как-то странно. Флеш-плеер появляется, но сам контент не подгружается, как будто ошибка в назначении имени ролика swf.

Статический код (как в примере Адоба - все работает)

```
object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="menu.swf" width="1200" height="300">
<param name="movie" value="menu.swf"/>
```

Одна из динамических попыток (не работает)

```
var node=document.createElement('object');
document.body.appendChild(node);

node.type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
node.data="menu.swf"
//node.name="menu.swf"

node.width="300"
node.height="300"

var p=document.createElement('param');


p.name="movie"
p.value="menu.swf"
node.appendChild(p)
```

Перепробовал кучу вариантов. Ничего... (((
Причем проблема именно для IE11, в предыдущих версиях никакой проблемы в динамическом создании флеш-объекта не было:

```
var node=document.createElement('object');
document.body.appendChild(node);

node.classid= "clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
node.movie="menu.swf"

    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем у меня было два косяка.

Один по теме вопроса. Добавление в DOM объекта должно быть **СТРОГО ПОСЛЕ** того как заданы все свойства/атрибуты объекта.
Вариант со свойствами (работает):

```
var node=document.createElement('object');
    node.type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    node.data="menu.swf"        
    node.width="300"
    node.height="300"
    document.body.appendChild(node);
```

Вариант с атрибутами (работает):

```
var node=document.createElement('object');
    node.setAttribute('type',"application/x-shockwave-flash")
    node.setAttribute('data',"menu.swf")
    node.setAttribute('width',"300")
    node.setAttribute('height',"300")
    document.body.appendChild(node);
```

Второй косяк был в том, что на страничке стоял метатэг:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

Дело в том, что если стоит метатэг типа этого, то внедрять флеш в IE нужно по-старому, через classid (хотя говорят, что хитрый IE11 не всегда слушается этого тэга). Иначе, если стоит edge или вообще убран этот метатэг, то в IE11 надо грузить флеш по-новому - через type="application/x-shockwave-flash".

Answer (score 0):

используйте готовую и популярную библиотеку: [swfobject.js](https://github.com/swfobject/swfobject)

Comment: Ну можно использовать и статический метод, можно и  swfobject.js, но хотелось бы понять именно данный трабл с ИЕ11 и флешом. Как я уже написал, ранее в ИЕ я без всяких swfobject.js и прочего легко динамически создавал флеш-объект.

Comment: В таком случае Вам нужно писать правильный javascript и работать с аттрибутами элемента как надо, а не как хочется. Скорее всего в этом причина неудачи. Например: node.setAttribute('classid', 'clsid:tatata') и так все аттрибуты установить, а не как Вы сделали напрямую

Comment: Ну как уж только не работал ))) И как надо и как хочется и назначал атрибуты вместо параметров. Вообщем так как раньше прокатывало с classid, теперь ни разу не прокатывает. Но! Флеш-плеер все же внедряется в страничку, просто надо ПРАВИЛЬНО указать путь к загружаемому мувику. Проблема на 99% в этом. Еще одна тонкость: при статическом внедрении, от узла object отходит подузел param. Ранее (до IE11 и с classid при динамическом создании не надо было это точно повторять. Тут я как только не делал: и подузел создавал и не создавал. Нивкакую (((